# how to connect react js

Tags: html, reactjs

Hello guys i'm new for use react, i have problem because my react js cannot working.
This is my code
Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(`<h1>

Hello World`</h1>

, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I want to connect my index.js and show hello world properly

Comment: [cannot working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a useful description of the problem. You need to tell us what is actually happening, including quoting any error messages shown on the browser's developer tools console.

Comment: Also, you're initial code had all sorts of formatting errors. I tried to fix it, but might have put some backticks in the wrong place. Please take care to format your code properly.

Answer (score -1):

Probably just the following piece of code

```
ReactDOM.render(`<h1>Hello World`</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Should be corrected with**

```
ReactDOM.render({<h1>Hello World</h1>}, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I that that's a formatting error in the attempt to transcribe the code to SO and not the actual problem. Your corrected code won't work as you've introduced a different error.

Comment: I mean yeah, we need to see what's logging ? BTW What's the error here @Quentin that the answer has introduced ?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the quotes in the first argument. It's like writing html. But if you have multiple sibling elements put them inside one parent element. Try:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Always make sure you are installing react properly using npx via the terminal with the following command `npx create-react-app appname` Make sure your app name isn't in capital letters at all.

And be sure to work in `App.js` to implement all your components and create a subfolder called "Components"

**Never** work inside of your index.html when working with React. All your HTML and JS will be done inside of your components.

After installing it make sure you start up the server with the following command `npm start`

For example:

### Component.js (this is a js file inside of your components folder)

```
import React from "react";

const Component = () => {
 return(
  <h1>Hello World</h1>  //Your HTML goes here
};

export default Component; //Here you export the component to be used inside of your App.js
```

### App.js

```
import './index.css'
import Nav from "./Components/Component"; // Here you import your exported component


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component/> // Here is the component that your imported and can now use on your website
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

for more information on react, here are some resources:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZVQJkKY_p0

Hope this helps!

Okayyy bye!